# Fetching authors of posts and order of promises using Redux

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, promise, react-redux

**Using React Native and Redux, I am trying to first fetch a number of posts, and then fetch the corresponding authors.**

I am facing two problems:

1. How can I fix the order of my `catch` and `then` statements? I want to say: If posts could not be fetched, dispatch the failure action, stop and don't do anything else (i.e. do *not* try to fetch the authors). But if posts were fetched successfully, go ahead and fetch the authors.
2. What do I need to change in my code below to ensure `posts` gets passed to `fetchAuthorsForPostsFromAPI`? As is, `posts` is `undefined` within `fetchAuthorsForPostsFromAPI`.

---

```
// fetches the posts from the API
export const fetchPostsFromAPI = () => ( dispatch ) => {

    // dispatch action: currently fetching posts from the API
    dispatch( fetchingPosts() );

    // prepare the promise that fetches the posts from the API
    let loadPosts = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
        // uses dummy data for now
        if( !postsInitial ) {
            reject( "Error: Could not get posts" );
        }
        else {
            resolve( postsInitial );
        }
    });

    // actually fetch the posts from the API
    return loadPosts
        // if error fetching the posts from the API
        .catch( error => dispatch( fetchPostsFailure( error ) ) )
        // if success fetching the posts from the API
        .then( posts => dispatch( fetchPostsSuccess( posts ) ) )
        // fetch authors for posts from the API
        .then( posts => fetchAuthorsForPostsFromAPI( posts, dispatch ) )
}
```

---

```
// is dispatched if the posts were succesfully fetched from the API
function fetchPostsSuccess( posts ) {
    return {
        type: PostConstants.FETCH_POSTS_SUCCESS,
        postsWithoutAuthors: posts,
    }
}
```

---

```
// is called when the posts have been fetched successfully from the API
// fetches the author for each post from the API
function fetchAuthorsForPostsFromAPI( posts, dispatch ) {

    console.log( "posts:", posts ); // logs "posts: undefined"

    // dispatch action: currently fetching authors of posts from the API
    dispatch( fetchingAuthorsForPosts() );

    // prepare the promise that fetches the authors for the posts from the API
    let loadAuthors = new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {

        // for each post
        posts.map( post => {

            // find the author by id
            const authorObj = authors.find( author => {
                return author.id === post.authorId
            });

            // if error finding author
            if( !authorObj ) {
                reject( "Error: Author for this id could not be found!" );
            }

            // if success finding author, keep going
            else {
                post.author = authorObj;
            }

        });

        // resolve
        resolve( posts );
    });

    // actually fetch the authors from the API
    return loadAuthors
        // if success fetching the authors for the posts from the API
        .then( posts => dispatch( fetchPostsAuthorsSuccess( posts ) ) )
        // if error fetching the authors for the posts from the API
        .catch( error => dispatch( fetchPostsAuthorsFailure( error ) ) );
}
```

Comment: Try returning the posts in the previous .then(). I mean after dispatch the fetchPostsSuccess function do `return posts`. But I believe that the correct way to do this is make the second fetch inside the .then() of the first.

Answer (score 0):

There is several ways to solve the problem. Imho using async/await is much easier than promise.

```
    async const fetchData = () => (dispatch) =>  {
      var postResult = await getPosts(dispatch);
      if (postResult) {
        await getAuthors();
      }
    }

    const getPosts = async () => (dispatch) =>  {
      var apiResponse = await getPostsFromApi();
      if(apiResponse)
      {
        //dispatch something
        return true;
      } else {
        //dispatch error
        return false;
      }
    }
```